DQN learning Cartpole reward graph
I've tried to make a DQN model for the simple cartpole game, but after training it for almost 3000 episodes, it produces a really weird reward graph and I'm not sure if it's even training correctly.
I've seen other posts where people didn't have a target network, didn't wait to train the model until they've had enough previous experiences and other issues. I've looked and tried to address all these issues, and this is what I got.

Here's the code:
dqn.py:
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim=256):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(state_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, action_dim)

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        return self.fc2(x)

agent.py:
import torch
import flappy_bird_gymnasium
import gymnasium
from dqn import DQN
from experience_replay import ReplayMemory
import itertools
import yaml
import random
from pathlib import Path
from torch import nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import numpy as np

device = "gpu" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

class Agent():

    def __init__(self, hyperparameter_set):
        with open(str(Path().resolve()) + "\\hyperparameters.yml", "r") as file:
            all_hyperparameters_set = yaml.safe_load(file)
            hyperparameters = all_hyperparameters_set[hyperparameter_set]

        self.env_name = hyperparameters["env_id"]
        self.replay_memory_size = hyperparameters['replay_memory_size']
        self.mini_batch_size = hyperparameters['mini_batch_size']
        self.epsilon_init = hyperparameters['epsilon_init']
        self.decay_rate = hyperparameters['epsilon_decay']
        self.epsilon_min = hyperparameters['epsilon_min']
        self.network_sync_rate = hyperparameters["network_sync_rate"]
        self.lr = hyperparameters["lr"]
        self.discount_factor_g = hyperparameters["discount_factor_g"]
        self.hidden_layers = hyperparameters["hidden_layers"]
        self.stop_on_reward = hyperparameters["stop_on_reward"]

        self.loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
        self.optimizer = None

        self.LOG_FILE = str(Path().resolve()) + "\\logs.txt"
        self.MODEL_FILE = str(Path().resolve()) + "\\models.pt"
        self.GRAPH_FILE = str(Path().resolve()) + "\\graphs.png"

    def run(self, is_training=False, render=False):
        env = gymnasium.make(self.env_name, render_mode="human")

        obs, _ = env.reset()

        reward_per_episode = []

        num_actions = env.action_space.n
        num_states = env.observation_space.shape[0]

        policy_dqn = DQN(num_states, num_actions, self.hidden_layers)

        if is_training:
            policy_dqn.train()
            memory = ReplayMemory(self.replay_memory_size)

            epsilon_history = []
            epsilon = self.epsilon_init

            self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(policy_dqn.parameters(), lr=self.lr)

            target_dqn = DQN(num_states, num_actions, self.hidden_layers).to(device)
            target_dqn.load_state_dict(policy_dqn.state_dict())

            step_count = 0

            best_reward = float('-inf')
        else:
            policy_dqn.eval()
            policy_dqn.load_state_dict(torch.load(self.MODEL_FILE))

        for episode in itertools.count():
            state, _ = env.reset()
            state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float, device=device)
            episode_reward = 0.0
            terminated = False

            while (not terminated) and episode_reward < self.stop_on_reward:

                if is_training and random.random() < epsilon:
                    action = env.action_space.sample()
                    action = torch.tensor(action, dtype=torch.int64, device=device)
                else:
                    with torch.no_grad():  
                        action = torch.argmax(torch.squeeze(policy_dqn(torch.unsqueeze(state, 0)), 0))  

                new_state, reward, terminated, _, info = env.step(action.item())
                new_state = torch.tensor(new_state, dtype=torch.float, device=device)

                episode_reward += reward

                reward = torch.tensor(reward, dtype=torch.float, device=device)

                if is_training:
                    memory.append((state, action, new_state, reward, terminated))

                    step_count += 1

                state = new_state

            if is_training:
                if episode_reward > best_reward:
                    log_message = f"New best reward {episode_reward: 0.1f}, {(episode_reward - best_reward):0.1f} increase from previous best"
                    with open(self.LOG_FILE, 'a') as file:
                        file.write(log_message + '\n')
                    torch.save(policy_dqn.state_dict(), Path(self.MODEL_FILE)) 
                    best_reward = episode_reward 

                if len(memory) > self.mini_batch_size:
                    mini_batch = memory.sample(self.mini_batch_size)

                    self.optimize(mini_batch, policy_dqn, target_dqn)

                    if step_count > self.network_sync_rate:
                        target_dqn.load_state_dict(policy_dqn.state_dict())
                        step_count = 0

                    epsilon = max(epsilon * self.decay_rate, self.epsilon_min)
                    epsilon_history.append(epsilon)
            print(epsilon)
            reward_per_episode.append(episode_reward)

    def optimize(self, mini_batch, policy_dqn, target_dqn):
        states, actions, new_states, rewards, terminations = zip(*mini_batch) 

        states = torch.stack(states)
        actions = torch.stack(actions)
        new_states = torch.stack(new_states)
        rewards = torch.stack(rewards)
        terminations = torch.tensor(terminations).float().to(device)

        with torch.no_grad():
            target_q = rewards + (1 - terminations) * self.discount_factor_g * target_dqn(new_states).max(dim=1)[0] 

        current_q = torch.squeeze(torch.gather(policy_dqn(states), 1, torch.unsqueeze(actions, 1)), 1) 

        loss = self.loss_fn(current_q, target_q)

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=" Train or test model.")
    parser.add_argument("hyperparameters", help='')
    parser.add_argument("--train", help="Training mode", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    dql = Agent(hyperparameter_set=args.hyperparameters)

    if args.train:
        dql.run(is_training=True)
    else:
        dql.run(is_training=False, render=True)

hyperparameters.yml:
cartpole1:
  env_id: CartPole-v1
  replay_memory_size: 100000
  mini_batch_size: 32
  epsilon_init: 1
  epsilon_decay: 0.9995
  epsilon_min: 0.05
  network_sync_rate: 10
  lr: 0.001
  discount_factor_g: 0.99
  stop_on_reward: 100000
  hidden_layers: 10
  enable_double_dqn: True

I've tried playing around with the hyperparameters (even copying the parameters from stable-baselines3), but it still does the same thing.
If it is normal, this training does seem excessively slow, so what would I need to do for quicker training? Increasing network_sync rate, decreasing the epsilon decay or something else. I'm really unsure.
After experimenting some more with the hyperparameters, I was able to get something much more sensible: .
I slowed down the epsilon decay, increased the learning rate and increased the number of hidden layers.
